# why is my plane flying backwards in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

My plane is flying backwards in Unity

I'm making a plane game thing in which you have to dodge obstacles

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerControllerX : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody rb;
private float rollSpeed = 8f;
private float pitchSpeed = 3f;
private float horizontalInput;
public float forwardAcceleration = -5f;
public float rotateInput;
public float bankSpeed = 1.45f;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
   
  
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * 2);
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    rotateInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * pitchSpeed * Time.deltaTime;  
   horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rollSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    
    transform.Translate(Vector3.up * bankSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Rotate(0,0,rotateInput * 10);
    transform.Rotate(horizontalInput * 5,0,0);
    transform.Translate(forwardAcceleration,0,0);
    
 }
}
```

I tried reversing
`public float forwardAcceleration = 5f;`
with
`public float forwardAcceleration = -5f;`

All positions and rotations are all Vector3(0,0,0);

There are no errors that the IDE detected, it's just that I want my plane to fly forwards instead of backwards.

It was working fine before but idk what happened.

Comment: by the way I'm a noob.

Comment: why would you want to walk forwaard by taking 5 paces backwards? (forwardAcceleration = -5f;)

Comment: I just tried it assuming that it will fix it man, idk I literally started game dev this month

Comment: I also did public float forwardAcceleration = 5f; but it had the same result

Comment: Well 5 forward and 5 backwards cant be the same. There must be something else going on

Comment: in general you will want to use `Time.deltaTime` on all your `Translate` and `Rotate` calls otherwise your code fully depends on the frame-rate ;)

Comment: And also in general: If you are using **physics** (Rigidbody) then you do **not** want to move / rotate your objects through `Transform` at all! You rather want to go through the `Rigidbody` and either stick to forces or use `MovePosition`/`MoveRotation` - makes no sense to mix both